# cron job email customization

Tags: cron

I have a list of cronjobs where some executes daily and others execute very 15 minutes.
I do want to receive an email for the ones executed daily, but wants email disabled for the ones executing every 15 minutes(or maybe receive a daily email), is there a way to do this in crontab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop the output from being e-Mailed for a specific cron entry, redirect the output for those cron to /dev/null.  Suffix your cron entry with this to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR:

`> /dev/null 2>&1`

While you can redirect different types of output different ways, for more advanced handling such as digests, you will need to script it.

As a side note, important notifications shouldn't be e-Mailed.  Use central logging (syslog) or monitoring. (nagios)

Comment: To script a digest just change > /dev/null 2>&1 to >> /var/log/{filename} 2>>&1 and add a cron entry to send and truncate that file on a schedule.

Comment: Good idea on that.  Really, just `cat` would be enough as a cron entry.